# Defining an Executable in Cabal that is Not Installed

Tags: haskell, cabal

Is there a cabal attribute of `executable` that means "don't install this executable".

E.g. in `myproject.cabal` I would have:

```
executable install_exe
   ...
executable support_exe -- not to be installed via cabal install
   install: False
```

EDIT: I realize I can *might* be able to say something from the command line to just get that one, but I am looking for something that can be defaulted in the cabal file.

Thanks!

Comment: What are you hoping *will* happen to `support_exe` instead of installation? (Why is it important that it be built at all?)

Comment: Right on. Thanks. I use these tools for static offline project tasks. E.g. artifact generation, consistency checking, etc... and a legacy testing framework. Someday I'll wire up the tester to the cabal testing interface, but some of the other static tasks are kind of hard for me to fit into the cabal environment with my level of cabal knowledge. (I love cabal though.)

Comment: For offline project development tasks, I recommend separating the program into its own package. (That's what e.g. gtk2hs does with its gtk2hs-buildtools package.) And yes, cabal has facilities for building testing-only artifacts. That's part of why I asked -- I can write up a separate answer discussing the use of these two techniques if we can get some details about what's actually wanted. (I think this is a bit of an X/Y problem -- you're shaving the wrong yak.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `buildable: False` inside the `executable` stanza to instruct cabal not to build `support_exe`. If you want a way to enable it in certain circumstances, you can protect this clause with a build flag. An incomplete example follows.

```
flag support
    description: Build and install supporting executables
    default: False

executable support_exe
    if !flag(support)
        buildable: False
```